# How to bind nested JSON Data in XML

Tags: sapui5

I want to bind JSON Data to view I have tried as below:

XML:

```
<m:Select id="Employee" items="{Employee>/EmployeeList}">
<c:Item key="{Employee>key}" text="{Employee>value}" />
<m:layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
</m:layoutData>
```

This is how my JSON data is :

```
 var xyz = {
    "Employee": {

        "EmployeeList": [{
                "key": "ram",
                "value": "ram"
            },
            {
                "key": "raj",
                "value": "raj"
            },
            {
                "key": "rani",
                "value": "rani"
            }
        ]
    }
}
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(xyz);
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

I have a select box in view I want to show the employee names as dropdowns in view page.How to bind this XML.Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks to me that you have forgotten the '>' after the model name in your binding. "{Employee/EmployeeList}" should be "{Employee>/EmployeeList}"

Comment: sorry it was by mistaken i have kept but dropdown values are not showing in xml view

Comment: Do you get the right amount of empty items in your dropdown?

Comment: yes i got but the values are not displaying

Comment: It's because you have to get the values from the model. <c:Item key="{Employee>key}" text="{Employee>Value}" /> should work.

Comment: <m:Select id="Employee"  items="{Employee>/EmployeeList}" > <c:Item key="{Employee>key}" text="{Employee>Value}" /> I have tried this but the data is not displaying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple wrong assumptions:

```
items="{Employee>/EmployeeList}"
```

Here you assume that you have a model with the name `Employee` which has a top-level attribute `EmployeeList`.

In fact you have a model with no name and with a top-level attribute `Employee`.

You have the choice to:

- change your binding
- change your model

#### Option A: Change your binding:

This is your option if you cannot change the model (because it comes from your backend that way).

Remove the model name from your binding (since your model does not have a name). Build the correct path to your list. At the top of xyz there is a property `Employee` which is an object that has the property `EmployeeList`.

```
<m:Select id="Employee" items="{/Employee/EmployeeList}">
    <c:Item key="{key}" text="{value}" />
    <m:layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
    </m:layoutData>
</m:Select>
```

#### Option B: Change your model

If you are not satisfied with your model structure and think that your binding makes sense, you can also alter the model.

First, change your object so that the EmployeeList is your top level structure:

```
 var xyz={   
   "EmployeeList":[  
      {  
        "key":"ram",
        "value":"ram"
      },
      {  
        "key":"raj",
        "value":"raj"
      },
      {  
        "key":"rani",
        "value":"rani"
      }
   ]
}
```

When setting your model to your view, also provide the name that you expect in the binding:

```
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "Employee");
```

Comment: I have changes the binding and got the values thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you are setting your model on your view as unnamed model. 
So, the correct binding is:

```
<m:Select id="Employee" items="{/Employee/EmployeeList}">
    <c:Item key="{key}" text="{value}" />
         <m:layoutData>
                <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
         </m:layoutData>
</m:Select>
```